# Intellij - Split Screen Creates Duplicate

Tags: intellij-idea

When I have two Java files, and I want to compare them side-by-side, I split them vertically.  However, I end up with 3 Java files, because it duplicates the one I split, instead of just moving it.

Is there a way to change the behavior such that it just splits the two files I have open, rather than creating a 3rd?

Comment: Why don't you compare the files using IntelliJ's "Compare two files" action (Ctrl+D)?

Comment: I don't want to compare them as much as just refer to one while editing the other.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is not possible. The concept of a split is just that, to split an editor. See [Splitting and Unsplitting Editor Window](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/splitting-and-unsplitting-editor-window.html) in the help guide. You can create a second editor window by dragging a tab off the main editor window. See [Detaching Editor Tabs](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/detaching-editor-tabs.html) in the help guide. Note, if you already have a split in place, you can drag a file from one split pane to the other.

You can also write a macro to accomplish what you want.

1. Give the tab you want to split focus
2. From the menu: *Edit > Macros > Start Macro Recording*
3. Record the following sequence:
4. Right click on the tab and split it
5. Type <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> (or <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>F4</kbd>) to close the original window
6. Stop the macro (either view the popup in the bottom or via the *Edit > Macros > Stop Macro Recording*)
7. In the dialog, give the macro a name.

You can now either run the macro from *File > Edit > Macros*, or you can map a keyboard shortcut to it. See [Binding Macros with Keyboard Shortcuts](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/binding-macros-with-keyboard-shortcuts.html) in the help guide for how to do such.

Answer (score 19):

Not sure when this feature was added, but you can simply right-click the tab and choose **Move Right** ; it has the effect of splitting horizontally and then closing the old tab.

Comment: In version 2019.02 this right click menu item is called "Split and Move Right". If you already have the tabs split, the a new menu item is available called "Move to Opposite Group"

Answer (score 0):

Don't use *Split Vertically* or *Split Horizontally* actions!

Instead, you can use ***Split and Move Right*** and ***Split and Move Down*** actions.

---

You can press **Ctrl + Shift + A**, and type "split ..." then choose the action.

[image]

---

Also, you could add shortcuts  for them,

[image]